# "Chess" words in Spanish

Tags: vocabulario

No, not what you think...

Spanish is the only language I know offhand where the chess piece symbols (RDACT) contain a vowel. Do you know a website where I can find Spanish words consisting only of these letters? (Loanwords discouraged.) Examples: "dar", "cada". (If the list is small you can run a regex/grep over a dictionary and post it)

Comment: And also p for péon?

Comment: @jonathanjo: Indeed, but pawns rarely get a symbol in chess notation, so I purposely omitted that one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ubuntu has a Spanish equivalent of the [English word list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Words_(Unix)) found on all Unix systems (for spelling checking).

When I run `grep -E -i '^[RDACT]+$' /usr/share/dict/spanish` on it, I get the following results:

```
a
acarar
acatar
acatarrar
acta
ad
adara
adatar
adra
adrada
adrar
ara
arada
arar
arca
arcada
arcar
arda
arra
arracada
arta
artar
ata
atacada
atacar
atada
atar
atracada
atracar
ca
caca
cada
car
cara
caraca
carada
carca
carda
cardada
cardar
carra
carraca
carrada
carta
cata
catar
catarata
catata
catatar
catraca
daca
dada
dar
dardada
data
datar
rada
radar
rara
rata
ta
tac
taca
tacada
tacar
tara
tarara
tarda
tardar
tarta
tata
traca
tractar
trata
tratar
```

Comment: THX, the list was longer than expected (by sampling in Google Translate). No luck obtaining a Fischer Random starting position :-) but I surely will find a way to milk some problem chess lulz of it (given that I already published a bit in a Spanish problem chess journal...)